# XCode: How to link auto generated xcframework

Tags: xcode, xcframework

I have a XCode project depends on a xcframework, which would be generated by a external shell script (by `xcodebuild -create-xcframework`)

the question is: How to make XCode run the shell script before build?

**NOTE:**

- I have added a `New Run Script Phase` in the `Build Phases`, but before the shell script being run, the error occurred: `There is no XCFramework found at xxx`

  - for auto generated source file, it works fine if it was added to the `Output Files` in the `New Run Script Phase`
  - however, for the xcframework, it does not work, even if the xcframework has been added to `Output Files`

XCode version: 13.4.1